# how to confirm dates are valid in google big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a Birthdate field that has YYYY-MM-DD in it.

I'm using the below statement:

```
select 
  farm_fingerprint(cast(P.Key as string)) as person_id 
  , EXTRACT(YEAR from P.BirthDate) as year_of_birth
  , EXTRACT(MONTH from P.BirthDate) as month_of_birth
  , EXTRACT(DAY from P.BirthDate) as day_of_birth
  , DATETIME(TIMESTAMP (CONCAT(CAST(P.BirthDate as string), ' 00:00:00')))
  , P.Birthdate
from person P;
```

my question is about the BirthDate Field.  How do I ensure that this is a valid date prior to conversion?

If the value is bad, EXTRACT() will fail.  Does COALESCE() work on failed functions? if not, how do I compensate and set null?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you get? Unless I'm missing something, it shouldn't be possible to have an invalid value inside a date column.

Comment: Thanks.  that's what I get for not paying attention to a question posed to me.  It's one of those days.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar kind of requirement where we filter out invalid records using SAFE_CAST()

```
select * from invalid_date_fix_test
WHERE 
SAFE_CAST(dt_date AS TIMESTAMP) is not null and
timestamp(dt_date) > TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC('2019-03-24 00:37:35', DAY),INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi faced the data format issue since data was coming from multiple countries and in their local formats `mm/dd/yyyy` vs `dd/mm/yyyy` which I dealt with as below. hope it helps or gives a direction.

```
case when departureDate is null  or departureDate = '' then null
     when cast(substr(departureDate,1,2) as int64) > 12 then
     cast(parse_date('%d/%m/%Y',departureDate) as datetime)
   else cast(parse_date('%m/%d/%Y',departureDate) as datetime) end as departureDate
```